# Argument Usage: ti=.{.(*i.)}

Tags: j

I'm trying to get my head around `J`. In the `easy-j.pdf` (available [here](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Guides/Getting_Started); page 19) introduction there is this hook:

```
ti=.{.(*i.)}.     NB. ti=times index generator
ti 2 5            NB. Usage
```

I understand the previous term: `2(*i.)5  NB. 2 times 0 1 2 3 4`

I can understand/imagine that `}.` takes the last element from the argument-list (above `2 5`) to create `(*i.)5`. But what makes it clear/obvious that somehow the argument-list is also passed to `{.` to retrieve the `2` (in my current understanding the argument is already used by `}.`)?

I hope this question is understandable to `J` experts.

Comment: The dictionary has an entry on [Trains](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help807/dictionary/dictf.htm) with pictures.

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful. I saw a similar picture in the brief-reference-pdf. In the meantime I sort of got the hang of this hook/fork

Comment: Also useful (I somehow didn't see this when posting): nuvoc [hook](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/hook) and [fork](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/fork)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ti` is actually a monadic fork with three tines that are all verbs. The way that this is executed is that the two outside tines `{.` and `}.` are executed on the argument `2 5` and the result is fed as left and the right arguments of the middle tine `(* i.)`, which is itself a hook.

In J fork operations are often symbolized with `f`, `g` and `h` standing for verbs and `x` and `y` representing left and right arguments and forks are evaluated like this:

`(f h g) y <-> (f y) h (g y)    NB. <-> is a meta symbol for equivalency - not J symbols`

In this case `f y` is `{. 2 5` and `g y` is `}. 2 5`

```
  {. 2 5
2
   }. 2 5
5
```

The middle tine of a fork is always dyadic because it is fed from the two outside tines and the construct for the dyadic hook `(* i.)` in the centre is

```
x (f g) y <-> x f (g y)


   2 (* i.) 5  NB. 2 * (i. 5)
0 2 4 6 8
```

Comment: So, I assume the key or core of a hook is this `(f h g) y <-> (f y) h (g y)`.  It seems to be that it is quite hard to know that a certain expression should be interpreted as a hook. But who knows, perhaps I'll get used to it.

Comment: Actually both hooks and forks are subsets of strings of verbs called trains. If the train has an odd number of verbs > 1 then it is a fork. If it is an even number of verbs then it is a hook.  So `(f g) y` is a hook `<-> y f (g y)` , `(f h g) y` is a fork `<-> (f y) h (g y)` , `(e f h g) y` is a hook `<-> y e ((f y) h (g y))` and `(d e f h g) y` is a fork `<-> ((d y) e ((f y) h (g y)))`. This allows you to build longer and longer trains that can be parsed consistently. A bit weird at first but it is consistent, so you get used to it.

Comment: (°□°） It is not yet clear to me when a verb is to be evaluated as monad or dyad.. Well, I might post other questions like that later. Thanks a lot so far.

Comment: The valence is certainly elemental to understanding how the verbs operate. To begin with a dyadic fork will evaluate as follows: `x (f h g) y <-> (x f y) h (x g y)` so all the verbs are dyadic. A monadic fork `(f h g) y <-> (f y) h (g y)` and here the two outside tines are monadic and the middle is dyadic. For a dyadic hook `x (f g) y <-> x f (g y)` so f is dyadic and g is monadic. For a monadic hook `(f g) y <-> y f (g y)` and f is dyadic and g is monadic. Those patterns are how forks and hooks are consistently evaluated. You have raised some good points.